# How to manually query posts title, content and image attachment thumbnail?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to manually query from an external php file the wordpress database and I want to extract the last 3 posts with: title, content, last (or first) image, and for that image, from wp_postmeta I want to get the thumbnail url.

I managed to get the title, content, image id, but I couldn't figure it out how to add another join for getting image thumbnail. This is what I have:

```
SELECT a.post_title title, max(c.guid) img_url, a.ID id
FROM wp_posts a

LEFT JOIN
(select post_parent, max(post_date_gmt) as latest_image_date from wp_posts
where post_type='attachment' GROUP BY post_parent) b 
on a.id=b.post_parent

LEFT JOIN wp_posts c
on c.post_parent=a.id 
and c.post_type='attachment' 
and b.latest_image_date = c.post_date_gmt where c.guid IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY a.post_title ORDER BY a.ID
```

The image thumbnail is in `wp_postmeta (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)` table, looking like this: `58435, 6711, _wp_attachment_metadata, a:6:{s:5:"width";s:4:"1024";s:6:"height";s:3:"683"...`

I could see I get the image id in `c.id` and all it needs is another `JOIN` to also get data from `wp_postmeta` for the field where `meta_key="_wp_attachment_metadata" and post_id=c.id`.

Can anyone help me with completing the query? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I chose another solution (at least temporary) because it adds horizontal capabilities: I created a completely empty custom page (I had to manually remove some actions/filters to get it empty) in the other site (the one to be included) which exports data in json format. I get that data and print it as I need in the current site.

```
<?php
$args= array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6
    //if there are sticked posts they will also appear beside the 2 if we run this in a separate php file, not included in theme
);
$ii = 0;
query_posts($args);
if( have_posts() ) :


  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $permalink = get_permalink();
    $titlu = get_the_title();
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'numberposts'    => 1
    );
    $images = get_posts($args);
    $j = 1;
        foreach ($images as $i) :

        $ii++;//am preluat doar o poza, e ok numaratoarea
        $j++;
        $poza_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'thumbnail');
        $arr[$ii] = array('titlu' => $titlu, 'url' => $permalink, 'poza_thumb' => "".$poza_thumb[0], 'poza_width' => "".$poza_thumb[1], 'poza_height' => "". $poza_thumb[2], 'articol' => $excerpt);

        endforeach;

    endwhile;

    echo json_encode($arr);//we send json as array
else :

endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but here to help future answer seekers

Update the query as needed. This current query will select post that have attachments. It returns the attachment ID and guid, the post ID and title along with the category name and term_id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID,p.post_title, a.ID as attach_id, a.guid, t.name, t.term_id FROM $wpdb->posts as a
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts as p on p.ID = a.post_parent
AND a.post_type = 'attachment' AND a.post_mime_type = 'image/png'

JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as tr on tr.object_id = p.ID
JOIN $wpdb->terms as t on t.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id
AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'

AND p.post_type = 'post'
AND p.post_status = 'publish';
```

Answer (score -1):

You should save your time and use wordpress functions :

- make a plugin
- or include wp-load.php in your script

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files

Comment: Thank for reply. The site I want to include title+link+thumbnail is another install of wordpress, so don't the functions and global variables mix?

Comment: Then why not simply use rss feed ? And if rss doesn't fit your needs, you should make a script (using wordpress functions as described in my answer) on the "source" site, and include it on the "destination" site.

Comment: Why should I use RSS if I am on the same server, same hosting account, just different database? :) Is is a lot faster like this (rss functionality is moved to feedburner, so another server) and it should be easier as I am just a step away: I can get the full size image, but I need just another JOIN to also get the thumbnail of that image. In the last case scenario I will use another query to get the thumbnail, but I would not like that :D

Comment: So why should you use custom sql queries if you can save your time and use wordpress functions or wordpress rss feed ?... :)

Comment: I will try it, even if I am afraid it might mix the wordpress global variables (I will have wp_load.php included from 2 different installations).

Comment: Thank you for your post and reply, it helped me chose the best solution for me for now. I up-voted the answer and posted the solution I chose.